# (Resolvido)ERROR: Flutter Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<OficioEnviado>

Tags: flutter, dart

estou tentando fazer um infinit scroll, tenho um consumo de uma api onde pego os dados e converto com minha model para json, quero inserir esses dados em variável, onde ao chegar no fim do scroll adicione sempre mais 10 itens, meu problema é na hora inserir os dados nessa variável, já tentei de varias formas mas sem sucesso, segue o print do erro e o código, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha Classe Principal

```
var oficiosEnviadosData = new List<OficioEnviado>();
  var oficiosEnviados = new List<OficioEnviado>();

  onLoad() async {
    oficiosEnviados = this.listPaginate(_currentPage, _limit);

    oficiosEnviadosData.addAll(oficiosEnviados);
    _currentPage++;
    print(oficiosEnviadosData);
  }

  listPaginate(int page, int perPage) async {
    var token = await LocalShared().getValueShared('token');

    var url =
        'http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/v1/oficio/lista?page=$page&perPage=$perPage';
    var header = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
    };

    var response = await http.get(url, headers: header);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Iterable decoded = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"];

      List<OficioEnviado> result =
          decoded.map((data) => OficioEnviado.fromJson(data)).toList();

      return result;
    }

    return response;
  }
```

Minha Model

```
class OficioEnviado {
  int idOfEnvio;
  int idDestinatario;
  String lido;
  String pendente;
  int idOficio;
  Oficio oficio;

  OficioEnviado(
      {this.idOfEnvio,
      this.idDestinatario,
      this.lido,
      this.pendente,
      this.idOficio,
      this.oficio});

  OficioEnviado.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idOfEnvio = json['idOfEnvio'];
    idDestinatario = json['idDestinatario'];
    lido = json['lido'];
    pendente = json['pendente'];
    idOficio = json['idOficio'];
    oficio =
        json['oficio'] != null ? new Oficio.fromJson(json['oficio']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['idOfEnvio'] = this.idOfEnvio;
    data['idDestinatario'] = this.idDestinatario;
    data['lido'] = this.lido;
    data['pendente'] = this.pendente;
    data['idOficio'] = this.idOficio;
    if (this.oficio != null) {
      data['oficio'] = this.oficio.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Oficio {
  int idRemetente;
  int idOficio;
  int idLocalRemetente;
  String numOficio;
  String ano;
  String dataEnvio;
  String horaEnvio;
  String descricao;
  String assunto;
  String texto;
  Remetente remetente;

  Oficio(
      {this.idRemetente,
      this.idOficio,
      this.idLocalRemetente,
      this.numOficio,
      this.ano,
      this.dataEnvio,
      this.horaEnvio,
      this.descricao,
      this.assunto,
      this.texto,
      this.remetente});

  Oficio.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idRemetente = json['idRemetente'];
    idOficio = json['idOficio'];
    idLocalRemetente = json['idLocalRemetente'];
    numOficio = json['numOficio'];
    ano = json['ano'];
    dataEnvio = json['dataEnvio'];
    horaEnvio = json['horaEnvio'];
    descricao = json['descricao'];
    assunto = json['assunto'];
    texto = json['texto'];
    remetente = json['remetente'] != null
        ? new Remetente.fromJson(json['remetente'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['idRemetente'] = this.idRemetente;
    data['idOficio'] = this.idOficio;
    data['idLocalRemetente'] = this.idLocalRemetente;
    data['numOficio'] = this.numOficio;
    data['ano'] = this.ano;
    data['dataEnvio'] = this.dataEnvio;
    data['horaEnvio'] = this.horaEnvio;
    data['descricao'] = this.descricao;
    data['assunto'] = this.assunto;
    data['texto'] = this.texto;
    if (this.remetente != null) {
      data['remetente'] = this.remetente.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Remetente {
  int idUsuario;
  String cpf;
  String senha;
  String email;
  String nome;

  Remetente({this.idUsuario, this.cpf, this.senha, this.email, this.nome});

  Remetente.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idUsuario = json['id_usuario'];
    cpf = json['cpf'];
    senha = json['senha'];
    email = json['email'];
    nome = json['nome'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id_usuario'] = this.idUsuario;
    data['cpf'] = this.cpf;
    data['senha'] = this.senha;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['nome'] = this.nome;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: O problema é que está inserindo dados de um tipo em uma variável de outro tipo. `List<OficioEnviado> result =
          decoded.map((data) => OficioEnviado.fromJson(data)).toList();` Acredito que o problema possa estar nessa linha aqui. Tentou debugar e verificar o que está recebendo de retorno do método `decoded.map`? Tente alterar o `List<OficioEnviado>` para `var` e ver o resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu método `listPaginate()` é assíncrono e não possuí um retorno tipado, o problema é este...

Faça a seguinte modificação:

```
  List<OficioEnviado> listPaginate(int page, int perPage) async {
    var token = await LocalShared().getValueShared('token');

    var url =
        'http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/v1/oficio/lista?page=$page&perPage=$perPage';
    var header = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
    };

    var response = await http.get(url, headers: header);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Iterable decoded = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"];

      List<OficioEnviado> result =
          decoded.map((data) => OficioEnviado.fromJson(data)).toList();

      return result;
    }

    return response;
  }
```

Quando você vai receber um método `async` você precisa utilizar o `await` quando for utilizar o seu retorno de forma síncrona, então mude a chamada para:

```
  onLoad() async {
    oficiosEnviados = await this.listPaginate(_currentPage, _limit);

    oficiosEnviadosData.addAll(oficiosEnviados);
    _currentPage++;
    print(oficiosEnviadosData);
  }
```

Fazendo estas duas pequenas mudanças teu código irá funcionar

Comment: Value cara, resolveu aqui